# DBAccess for iOS error while importing from mm file

Tags: ios, objective-c++, dbaccess

I'm trying to add DBAccess to my iOS project.
Importing from the AppDelegate works well but when importing from a .mm file or even when in a .mm file importing another class which imports DBAccess.h, I'm getting errors on the line (from DBAccess.h):
`+(void)setupTablesFromClasses:(Class)class...;`
The errors are:
(1) Expected ';' after method prototype
(2) Expected identifier

any help will be appreciated

Comment: does this error happen if you're importing into a .m (a regular Objective-C, not Obj-C++) file?

Comment: no, the error does not occur while importing from a .m file.
for example, importing from AppDelegate works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, the problem comes from the parameter name being 'class' which is a reserved word.  Changing it to something else solved the compilation issue for me.

```
+(void)setupTablesFromClasses:(Class)classDecl,...;
```

Hope this resolves the issue for you.